# How do package managers handle ordered dependencies?

Tags: maven, windows-installer, npm, pip, rpm

How do package managers like rpm, pip, msi, mvn, npm, etc. handle dependencies that need to be installed in a particular order? Also, how are circular dependencies handled? Are there design patterns for these types of requirements?

Comment: What do you mean that the dependencies "need to be installed in a particular order"? I believe, package managers let you express what needs to be installed, but not the order..?

Comment: A depends on B and C, and B must be installed before C.